# Badge numbers in per-site flair are not anti-aliased

Tags: bug, flair

I noticed that the text for the number of each type of badge is not anti-aliased on the per-site flair images, but it is anti-aliased on the global Stack Exchange flair images. The reputation and username texts for both are anti-aliased. Why are the badge numbers not getting love?

[image: The 5 almost looks like a 6! Is this a DMV test?]

Comment: Eagle-eyed and really bored, eh? :P

Comment: @MatthewRead: No, [this is boredom](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvXt.jpg).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to ask this myself. All my votes.